# uploaded video only audio is displayed

Tags: html, video

I am trying to upload an MP4 file. But with this specefic file only the sound content is displayed.

With all my other videos there is no problem only with this specefic one.

i  found the following SO question:

[HTML5 video of type video/mp4 playing audio only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586128/html5-video-of-type-video-mp4-playing-audio-only)

Where he suggest to find a converter.

Does anyone know if this could be the problem and how do i secure that regardless of what video my user uploads that it will always be able to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be a problem.

You have not written about your server limitations, so *if* you have the possibility to execute converters (like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)) then this is the best solution. This way you can also guarantee fixed resolution, framerate and various other properties, and your server won't eat up all the space if someone uploads a 2GB video... (Users can be dumb sometimes.)

If you *cannot* run ffmpeg on the server then try reading some about how can you detect codecs on your server, in the language you use, etc. Then, if you still want to, post a specific question.

Also try opening your videoplayer page with different browsers (Chrome, FF, IE at least). They might not support the codecs the same way.